# Getting Weird Data while Parsing Date

Tags: java, postgresql, parsing, timestamp

I want to parse date from string received from Textbox but some portion of value doesn't parsed and gave me some default values and store in my DB :

In my DB I have taken field type Timestamp without time zone in postgresql.

Following is my code :

```
Timestamp ts= null;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(command.getHolidayDate());
System.out.println("Date ::" + convertedDate);
System.out.println("T :: "+convertedDate.getTime());
System.out.println("Received :: "+command.getHolidayDate());
ts = new Timestamp(convertedDate.getTime());
entity.setHolidayDate(ts);
```

here entity.setHolidayDate store received date to DB.

System.our.println result :

```
Date ::Wed Jan 09 00:08:00 IST 2013
T :: 1357670280000
Received :: 08/09/2013
```

I am entering following date to textbox :

```
08/09/2013
```

In my DB table it stores as  :

```
2013-01-09 00:08:00
```

why it's save data like this I don't have any idea.
and one problem is that it's taking some random time as well that also I don't want.
Any suggestion on this.
Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have an issue with your `SimpleDateFormat` format...

`mm` is "Minute in hour", not the month.

So looking at `2013-01-09 00:08:00`, you can see that that `08` represents the hour.

We would assume that you want to be getting `2013-08-09 00:00:00`, which means you should be using a format of `MM/dd/yyyy` instead

Check out [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details

Comment: Sir I have displayed on console that `convertedDate.getTime()` and shows me something like `1357670280000`, how to interpret it ? what's it's meaning ? and I have used `MM instead of mm` and solved the problem.

Comment: `1357670280000` is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  This is how time is measured in Java